# List is appearing to be null when calling from AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, list

I am creating a web app in which I have a scenario where I am sending data in list in the back-end, the below example explains this,

My Modal

```
public class NavigationModal
{
    public int regId { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

My Function

```
    public int postData(List<NavigationModal> contents)
    {
        Session["data"] = contents;
        return 1;
    }
```

My Controller Name

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
```

Code in front end

```
var data = [];

function StoreDataInSession(regId, MyRegistrations) {
    var contents = {
        regId: regId,
        URL: window.location.pathname.split("/")[2] == null ? 'index' : window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]
    };
    data.push(contents);
    var newData = JSON.stringify({ 'contents': data });
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Navigation/postData',
        data: data,
        success: function () { ReDirectToAction(); }
    });
}
```

But my data is appearing to be null when I am debugging my controller, and when I see the data in console, it is coming properly.

What is my issue?

[image]

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates that your controller action as target from AJAX request throwing unhandled exception. Check the `postData` action and include what exception was thrown in your question (and use `JSON.stringify(data)` because you're setting `contentType` with `application/json`).

Comment: Did you add [HttpPost] in your action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your action method has wrong return type and HTTP method in this definition:

```
public int postData(List<NavigationModal> contents)
```

Note that a controller which receives JSON data from AJAX request must have at least `ActionResult` as return type (you can use `JsonResult` as alternative because of `dataType: json` setting) and specify `[HttpPost]` attribute because `type: POST` has been set in AJAX callback.

The correct setup for AJAX request should be like this example below:

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostData(List<NavigationModal> contents)
{
    Session["data"] = contents;
    return Json("true");
}
```

**AJAX callback**

```
var data = [];

function StoreDataInSession(regId, MyRegistrations) {
    var contents = {
        regId: regId,
        URL: window.location.pathname.split("/")[2] == null ? 'index' : window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]
    };
    data.push(contents);
    var newData = JSON.stringify({ 'contents': data });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("PostData", "Navigation")',
        data: newData,
        success: function () { ReDirectToAction(); }
    });
}
```